# Consuming JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read this link.

http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1

with this method:

```
$.getJSON(" http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1",function (json) {
    alert(json.length);
});
```

But it doesn't work, and I don't know the reason :(

Some one can help me?

[edit]

I just want to read, the "json.length" its was just a test. I tried this with another .json, and worked. I want to know if a need to use some method that read without problems.

Comment: You need to use `getJSON`, which is specifically for JSON.

Comment: There is no "length" property in this json object.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @CiroCorvino Try `{}.length`, Whatever error you get is the same error.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Wait at least 5 sec before answering :-P

Comment: @procrastinator When I know the answer, why the wait? Is it wrong?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Bekoz : 1. you look like flash gordon 2. i edited my comment to make it closer to my thoughts.

Comment: @procrastinator I am Canvas Gordon (flash is not supported in HTML5).

Comment: @PraveenKumar if the error it is a json empty array as you argue,  the first space before the address of the service maybe can create some problem to the ajax Jquery call done by getJSON

Comment: Start by understanding the data structure you are working with. go through the detailed explanation/tutorial in linked question

Comment: @charlietfl The comment for who? Me or OP? Is my answer right? I am planning to remove if it is not right.

Comment: @CiroCorvino Is my answer right? I am planning to remove if it is not right.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is an hypotesys.. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar for OP.

Comment: @charlietfl Also, I don't understand how this question is a dupe of that question. Do you mind explaining it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar question is so vague and really just asks how to read the data. No idea what they want from it, it's not clear. So the fundamentals are well detailed in duplicate

Comment: Oh okay... I feel I can easily find the issue OP is facing... The OP also mentioned that they don't know English. So it might be a reason too.

Comment: What kind of result were you expecting?

Comment: I just want to read, the "json.length" its was just a test. I tried this with another .json, and worked. I want to know if a need to use some method that read without problems.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable fetched is an object, instead of array, you need to use `Object.keys()`, which gives you the list of keys as an array and you can use the `.length` on it:

```js
$.getJSON("http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1", function(json) {
  alert(Object.keys(json).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One thing I noticed is, the following URL:

```
http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1
```

Doesn't have the CORS enabled. So, if you try accessing it, it throws an error in the Console, which is kinda silent. If you mean that, you need to request or make the JSON to have [**CORS Enabled**](http://enable-cors.org/index.html).